# Track User Location from Site Activity in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, site-collection

Below image shows the default `Site audit log or Site Collection Web Analytics Reports`.

[image]

But I need to track the users location, `From which location site is accessing by users or site is active?`

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible with the build in analytics. For more insights on couple of projects I used google analytics you can either embed it in custom master page (even if that is the only customization and rest is out of the box) I read as well about a way of doing it without customization of master. http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/02/26/how-to-add-google-analytics-to-sharepoint-without-modifying-the-master-page/

Comment: Here is another way to integrate GAnalytics: https://github.com/nils-a/ganalytics4sp

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to do that. You can use SharePoint custom Actions and inject your custom script in SharePoint. That should deal with the User locations.

For SharePoint ScriptLink Custom actions [refer](http://aaclage.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-include-user-custom-actions-and.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say. There is no Out of the box functionality available for this. The way to implement this,you need to build analytic definition for your portal and find the best way to share the User-profile data as parameters in the function.
Eg:Place,Name etc...

Comment: Oh Thankq #Sreeraj_Sree... I will try once with User-Profile data.

Answer (score 0):

How close to the truth do you need to get?

- Real close (Street level) --> Need to retrieve the location from the clients browser and deal with it for the current session. This is not tracked anywhere and you need to implement it yourself
- Area only (City / Region) --> Use the IP to locate the user. This will allow you to roughly get the region of the user. Use the IIS Logs for this. You have to implement this also...
- "Just general numbers" --> Use the office location in the user profile. Guess what... you need to implement it ;)
- Area only + lazy --> Use a 3rd party solution for site usage reporting by google or whatever like mentioned before